# How to fill dropddownlist from databse in .net

Tags: c#, sql, .net

below is the code I wrote to fill dropdown list from the database,and I am not getting where I did mistake..help me in finding out and correcting my mistake.

```
void filldistrict()
{
   DropDownList4.Items.Clear();
   DropDownList4.Items.Add("--District--");
   String q="select * from DLIST";
   SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(q,cn);
   SqlDataReader rec = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if (rec.Read())
       DropDownList4.Items.Add(rec.getValue(1).ToString);
   rec.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close - the only problem is this line:

```
if (rec.Read())
```

You can also use `new ListItem()` when adding to the `Items` collection.  You can use the overload that takes two strings that will set the text and the value, as well.

That will only get the first row of the returned records, not all of them.  What you want is to loop through the records in `rec`, like this:

```
void filldistrict()
{

    DropDownList4.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList4.Items.Add("--District--");
    String q="select * from DLIST";
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(q,cn);

    using (SqlDataReader rec = cmd.ExectueReader())
    {

        while (rec.Read())
        {
            DropDownList4.Items.Add(new ListItem(rec.GetValue(1).ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I used a `using` block with the reader so its automatically closed while the block is exited.  I would also suggest doing the same with your `SqlConnection`.

The alternative provided by Ali is also a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection sql_cnt=new SqlConnection("connectionString");
SqlCommand sql_cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from DLIST",sql_cnt);
Dataset dt_data=new Dataset();
SqlDataAdapter sql_adp=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
try
   {
      sql_cnt.Open();
      sql_adp.Fill(dt_data);
      sql_cnt.Close();
   }
catch(Exception err)
   {
      //Do something;
   }

DropDownList4.ValueMember="the name of the field which you want to be shown in dropdown list";
DropDownList4.DataSource=dt_data;
```

Comment: Thanx,let me try it and response you sir accordingly.